How to play Spotify music with other audio in flutter?
I want to play two audios together, for example Spotify music with my custom audio from my assets, so how can I do it?
I tried to use audioplayers package but it needs a music url to play and a Spotify music url it can't play. Is there other ways to do it?

Spotify makes money for audio streaming. Check https://developer.spotify.com/policy
